# loops in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, loops

I know exactly how to write both for loops and while loops, however I struggle with what comes after. For example, I did an interactive tutorial and was asked to write a for loop that adds numbers 1 through 10.

This is the syntax for the for loop:

```
{ 
    var currentSum = 0;
    for (var i=1; i<= num; i++) {
        currentSum += i; // <--
    }
    return current sum  // <--
}
console.log(sum(10))
```

I understand what is in regular writing, and I marked what I don't understand. I know what they mean, I just don't know why I was supposed to put them as opposed to something else and I don't get how I was supposed to know that those are the right things to code.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: This is not even valid javascript.  Can you please post something valid that at least will run.

Comment: there seems to be a the start of the function missing from your code? Shouldn't it start with function sum(num)

Answer (score 1):

1) currentSum += i; // <--

Refer to **[JavaScript Assignment Operators](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_operators.asp)**.
It can also be written as

```
currentSum = currentSum + i;
```

so this will store its previous value and keeping add new ones.

2)  return current sum  // <--

I feel this is invalid. It should return

```
 return currentSum  // will return the final value.
```

Answer (score 1):

With annotations, does this help?

```
function sum(num) <-- you seem to be missing this
{ 
    var currentSum = 0;           // <-- declare variable and assign it to 0
    for (var i=1; i<= num; i++) { // <--start a loop, with i as the counter, 
                                  //    starting at 1 and finishing at whatever 
                                  //    the value of num is
        currentSum += i;    // <-- take the current value of currentSum and 
                            //     add i to it, shorthand way of writing 
                            //     currentSum = currentSum + i
    }
    //return current sum  // <-- This line is completely wrong
    return currentSum;    // <-- Return the variable currentSum after all the 
                          //       looping and summing has finished

}
//consol.long(sum(10));    // <-- this line is also wrong, there is no such 
                           //     thing as consol.long
console.log(sum(10));      // <-- should be console.log, which is outputting 
                           //     the return value of the function call sum, 
                           //     passing in a value of 10 as the input 
                           //     parameter num, to the console.
                           //     Which in most browsers, can be located via F12
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function sum(n)
{ 
    var currentSum = 0;
    for (var i=1; i<=num; i++) {
        currentSum += i; // <-- 1*
    }
    return currentSum; // <-- 2*     
}
```

console.log(sum(10));

1* --> Short hand operator for addition. You can use either this or

```
   currentSum  = currentSum  + i
```

2* --> Seems to be a little incorrect here. The space should not be there. you are returning the computed value back from the function.